# If $f$ is twice differentiable and $\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)\,dt=f(x)$, show that there exist $a,b$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that$$\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)\, dt=f(x)\qquad\forall~x\in\mathbb{R}~\&~y>0$$Show that there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> [Source](https://librarykv2calicut.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/bmath-ugb-2019-1.pdf)

SOLUTION

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $F$ such that $F' = f.$ The given identity becomes$$F(x+y)-F(x-y) = 2yf(x)$$Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and differentiate the above identity with respect to $y$ and get$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)$$Differentiate again with respect to $y$ and get$$f'(x+y)-f'(x-y)=0, \: \forall y > 0$$Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, this holds true for any $x.$ Putting $x \to x+y$ it becomes$$f'(x)=f'(x+2y), \: \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \forall y > 0$$Hence $f'$ is constant, which means that $f=ax+b.$

This is my answer but someone said that

You actually have to show first that the given equation is true for $y\leq 0$, which is pretty trivial (but can't be ignored).

now I know how to prove that the equation is true for y<0 but I don't see why it is required to show that, I think the solution is complete even for y>0 alone

Comment: I agree that the equation for $y<0$ is not needed: just take $x_1=x_0-2y$ and then the $y<0$ case is covered. Also, I think it suffices that $f$ be differentiable, instead of twice differentiable?

Comment: Raunit.$y$ is a variable, real $(not\=0)$, so can take on any values $( \pm)$. Perhaps a remark about $y=0 $ would be in place. Nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to consider $y<0$. However you can be a little more explicit with your lasts step. Let $x_1 <x_2$ and take $y=\frac {x_2-x_1} 2$. Then $x_2=x_1+2y$ and $y>0$. So $f'(x_1)=f'(x_1+2y)=f'(x_2)$. This proves that $f'$ is a constant.